# Switching between threads in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a multi tab software. In every tab, I want to run different threads. When I switch from one tab to another, I suspend the related thread and then start a new thread for the new tab.

Sometimes when I quickly change tabs, my threads stop running and give me no exception or error. I understand this situation by debug. For this situation, I see that there are many same threads that seems in "Threads Window" but none of them is running.

I think suspending and starting of threads is not a good idea of programming but what should I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: "In every tab, i want to run different threads." - you probably don't want to do that....

Comment: If you want information on a different approach, you should explain what you want to achieve instead of how you implemented it. If you simply want the problem (switching quickly causes no threads to be running) to disappear, we'll need to see the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: How do you end up with this "one thread per tab" thing? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I guess the intention is to avoid UI freezing. If that is the reason try to use only one thread. Using many threads is quite complicated and very difficult to manage. Try to avoid several threads until unless u really need.

Comment: Don't tightly integrate threads to tasks. That just creates pain. Don't stop threads -- they shouldn't be doing work unless there's work you want them to do anyway, so there should be no need to stop them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'I have a multi tab software.'

OK, fine.

'In every tab, I want to run different threads'

I assume you mean that each tab has its own thread instance that interacts with that tab alone.  OK, fine, it's not an unusual design.  Maybe you interact with a different website on each tab, something like that.  That's OK.

'When I switch from one tab to another, I suspend the related thread and then start a new thread for the new tab'

NOT OK! Why are you doing this?  Can you not just switch tabs?  The other threads can continue to update/whatever components, (with Invoke/BeginInvoke), on the non-visible pages and, when you switch back, the changes will be displayed.

Hey! Coder! Leave the those threads alone!

'Sometimes when I quickly change tabs, my threads stop running and give me no exception or error. I understand this situation by debug. For this situation, I see that there are many same threads that seems in "Threads Window" but none of them is running'

I'm not surprised.  Start your one thread for each tab and, whatever it does, just leave it to get on with it.

'I think suspending and starting of threads is not a good idea of programming but what should I do to avoid this problem?'

Stop doing it!  Micro-managing threads at user-level nearly always ends in disaster.

Answer (score 3):

The usual design is to have one UI thread and multiple worker thread that:

- are started when there is a task to be executed and then 'disappear' when the task is completed
- are running permanently in the background in order to respond to some events (ie. items added to queue)

Comment: How can i do that? Could you please direct me some documentation?

Comment: Starting a thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d.aspx ;invoking a method on the GUI thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx

Comment: Explain what u want to achieve, What you do in each thread, why you need separate thread for each TAB?